# Swapping elements in array defined in class python

Tags: python, class, swap

I'm modelling a particle collision of two different species. I'm using a class to define each specie and a class for the arrays that hold the particle positions and speed.

When a collision occurs i have to swap the velocities of particle of specie A with the velocity of particle of specie B.

Classes are defined in a separate file as:

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.x=numpy.zeros((num,1)) #Position
        self.v=numpy.zeros((num,3)) #Velocity

class Species(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mass=[]
        self.spwt=[]
        self.np=[]
        self.np_alloc=[]
        self.part=[]
```

Species are created in the main file:

```
#variables to hold species
A = struct.Species()
B = struct.Species()

#set species data
A.mass = 1      
A.np = 0
A.spwt=spwt
A.np_alloc = num
A.part = struct.Particle(A.np_alloc)


B.mass = 1     
B.np = 0
B.spwt=spwt
B.np_alloc = int(cloud_den/spwt/cloud_len)
B.part = struct.Particle(B.np_alloc)
```

And when i try to swap velocities for particles

```
print A.part.v[p1]
print B.part.v[p2]

A.part.v[p1],B.part.v[p2]=B.part.v[p2],A.part.v[p1]

print A.part.v[p1]
print B.part.v[p2]
```

Output is:

```
[ 1000. 0. 0.]
[ 0. 0. 0.]
[ 0. 0. 0.]
[ 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to numpy, not to swap elements inside a class.

When you make:

```
A.part.v[p1]
```

you are creating a view of you array. Instead you need to create a copy:

```
c = numpy.copy(A.part.v[p1])
A.part.v[p1] = B.part.v[p2]
B.part.v[p2] = c
```

This should work.

Maybe there are more pythonic ways to perform the swap, but that should work.